# Browser adding double quotes in URI query string

Tags: html, query-string

My searches have been fruitless. I am coding a page that will have an anchor link to send query results to a second page to produced a tabulated csv file download.

The main page runs the query. I serialized the results as JSON and encoded them:

```
%5B%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2201%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A496%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2202%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A412%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2205%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A332%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2206%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A60%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2207%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A258%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2209%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A300%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A242%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A282%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A2%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A180%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2216%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A30%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B%22SELECT%5FREASON%22%3A%2217%22%2C%22IMPOSED%5FACTION%22%3Anull%2C%22DISP%5FTYPE%5FTEXT%22%3Anull%2C%22COUNT%22%3A6%2C%22DATE%22%3A20220712%7D%5D
```

The source on the page reflects this, but when I hover over the link (or go ahead and send it) all of the unencoded (plain text) portions are now quoted.

```
%27%5B%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"01"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A496%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"02"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A412%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"05"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A332%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"06"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A60%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"07"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A258%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"09"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A300%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"12"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A242%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"13"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A282%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"14"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A2%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"15"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A180%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"16"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A30%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%2C%7B"SELECT_REASON"%3A"17"%2C"IMPOSED_ACTION"%3Anull%2C"DISP_TYPE_TEXT"%3Anull%2C"COUNT"%3A6%2C"DATE"%3A20220712%7D%5D%27
```

The rendered html doesn't have the double quotes. How do I keep the browser from doing this?

Comment: I guess what you’re seeing is the debug output? it’s often represented as a string literal with all escaping applied

Comment: That was it. I ended up needing to substitute "~"  in place of %22 and then fixing that on the receiving end.

Comment: If you want to add it as an answer I'll confirm. It was easy to fix once I saw that the diagnostics were misleading.